# Как сделать идентификацию девайса не озадачивая пользователя?

Tags: android, идентификация

хотел применить deviceID, для идентификации устройства....
но, как подтвердилось - deviceID на планшете неожиданно вдруг однажды взял
и !!!!САМ!!!! ИЗМЕНИЛСЯ.

Идея в следующем:
хочу, чтобы приложение, позволяло пользователю заявить о своём мнении по конкретному вопросу.

Не хочу озадачивать его никакой процедурой идентификации.
Всё, что ему надо сделать - это поставить галочку в checkBox'е. (и всё!!!)

При клике на checkbox'e в базу Firebase улетает deviceID его устройства, говоря о том, что этот пользователь "согласен".

Всё работало хорошо, пока самопроизвольно не сменился deviceID. (это произошло вообще по непонятным для меня причинам. Я не перепрошивал устройство, а только переустановил androidStudio и обновил сборку приложения).

В результате в базе Firebase отражается неактуальная информация по количеству пользователей, заявивших "согласен". В ней теперь и старый deviceID, и новый.

ВОПРОС:
можно ли как-то решить этот вопрос.
(deviceID, EMEI, .... и другие идентификаторы  - похоже не вариант)

Хочу сделать идентификацию устройства (не пользователя)
и не хочу озадачивать пользователя лишними действиями (вводы логинов, паролей, отпечатка и прочего).

Comment: Ничего сделать нельзя, т.к. это теоретически невозможно. Даже если на серийник проца завязываться (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37298166/3212712) - это ничего не даст. При помощи паяльника и такой-то матери можно и его сменить. Вы можете лишь сокращать кол-во случаев смены ID девайса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, на самом деле "теоретически невозможно" - не совсем подходящий термин. Ибо смена процессора уже отсылает нас куда-то поближе к парадоксу корабля Тесея, так что вопрос превращается в своего рода философский: что считать устройством? Его "сердце" - процессор? Его корпус? Что-то ещё?

Comment: Конкретно какой `deviceId` имеется ввиду? В ходе эволюции Андроида это понятие несколько раз менялось, укажите конкретный Android API level и кусочек кода как вы получаете `deviceId`

Comment: если речь о получении ANDROID_ID через `Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)`, то он будет меняться при переустановке приложения.

Comment: да, я получаю ANDROID_ID через Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID).   Вы (ermakOff) говорите, что он меняется при каждой переустановке приложения.  Думаю это не совсем верно, ведь я переустанавливал приложение за эти 2 месяца раз 100, тестируя его, ..и ни разу не возникла проблема со сменой deviceID.     Она произошла именно после обновления студии--обновления сборки и очередном тестировании.  Возможно это совпадение с обновлением студии. Возможно что-то связано с новым buildGradle файлом всвязи с обновлением студии.

Answer (score 0):

благодарю, ребят, за быстрые ответы.

пока пришла такая идея:

1. при первой УСТАНОВКЕ приложения - отправляю значение в Firebase и сохраняю deviceID в SharedPreferences.
2. при каждой ЗАГРУЗКЕ приложения - получаю текущий deviceID, вытаскиваю из SharedPreferences старый ID - сравниваю значения.
3. Если deviceID изменился, то удаляю из Firebase запись со старым deviceID и записываю с новым deviceID.

Благодаря этому в Firebase не будет дублей одного и того же девайса с разными deviceID.
Дубль девайса (с новым id) появится лишь в том случае, если в пользователь удаляет приложение, затем по какой-то причине происходит смена deviceID и затем пользователь решает установить приложение снова.
Если же в эту "паузу между установками" самопроизвольная смена deviceID не происходила, значит всё ок.  Сама переустановка приложения не меняет deviceID (по состоянию на апрель 2020г.). По моему выводу, смена deviceID произошла именно после обновления версии AS--обновления BuildGradle и сборки приложения и переустановке на девайсе.

Если бы смог решить вопрос 1. сохранения значение deviceID не в SharedPreferences, а в память самого девайса, откуда не удаляются данные при удалении приложения.  или 2.возможность отследить удаление приложения и в за мгновение до удаления очистить Firebase от требуемого deviceID, ......... то можно было бы исключить дубли в любом случае.

Ниже код:

```
public class aktivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {


private SharedPreferences sp;                          // переменная класса базы данных в самом приложении андроиде
public DatabaseReference REF_usersTotal;               // переменная для ссылок по ветке с названием users_total
private String key_usersTotal = "users_total";         // так назвал ветку в Firebase (child)
private String key_deviceID = "deviceID";              // devicID - название поля в бд Firebase
private String curentDeviceID;                         // строковое значение текущего deviceID


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aktivity1);

    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);     // инициализирую бд андроида

    checkCountOfMyID_inFirebase();        // функция проверяет возможную смену deviceID и чистит бд Firebase

} // конец onCreate



// //функция проверки количества записей по моему deviceID в Firebase в ветке users_Total   (ветка это child)
public void checkCountOfMyID_inFirebase(){                                                       // если загрузил приложение из интернета в первый раз (или не в первый но небыло успешно считывания),  // то делаю проверку - есть ли в Firebase запись с моим текущим deiviceID.  // Если есть и их несколько, то удаляю все и создаю одну
    Query queryCheckMyID = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(key_usersTotal).orderByChild(key_deviceID).equalTo(curentDeviceID);     // запрос по записям с текущемим deviceID
    queryCheckMyID.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            long countOfMyIDinFDB = snapshot.getChildrenCount();          // получаю количество записей с текущим deviceID

            // вариант 1. если записей>2, значит надо всё удалить и внести только 1 запись со текущим deviceID
            if(countOfMyIDinFDB>=2){
                Query queryDelettingAllMyID = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(key_usersTotal).orderByChild(key_deviceID).equalTo(curentDeviceID);    // запрос
                queryDelettingAllMyID.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { // добавляю слушатель к запросу
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot DSS : snapshot.getChildren()){
                            DSS.getRef().removeValue();         // удаляю все записи
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
                MyUserClass user = new MyUserClass(curentDeviceID);              // готовлю класс для внесения в Firebase (в соответствии с моделью бд в FB, в котором только 1 поле с deviceID)
                REF_usersTotal.push().setValue(user);                            // и создаю новую и единственную запись
                sp.edit().putString("oldDeviceID", curentDeviceID).apply();      // сохраняю в SharedPreference значение текущего deviceID как теперь уже старое - oldDiveceID


                // вариант 2. если записей нет, значит либо пользователь действительно в первый раз загрузил приложение, либо случилась самопроизвольная смена deviceID
            }else if (countOfMyIDinFDB==0){
                // алгоритм:
                // 1. сравниваю значения ID старого и текущего.
                // 2. Если значения разные, значит произошёл самопроизвольная смена deviceID. Значит удаляю старую запись из Firebase и вношу новую

                String oldDeviceID = sp.getString("oldDeviceID", "none");          // извлекаю значение старого deviceID из SharedPreferences
                Query queryDelOldDiveciID = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(key_usersTotal).orderByChild(key_deviceID).equalTo(oldDeviceID);   // запрос по старому deviceID
                queryDelOldDiveciID.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {        // добавляю слушатель
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot dss :  snapshot.getChildren()){
                            dss.getRef().removeValue();         // уничтожаю запись со старым deviceID
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
                MyUserClass user1 = new MyUserClass(curentDeviceID);           //создаю новую запись в ветке users_Total c новым deviceID
                REF_usersTotal.push().setValue(user1);                         // вношу запись в Firebase
                sp.edit().putString("oldDeviceID", curentDeviceID).apply();     // сохраняю в SharedPreference значение текущего deviceID как теперь уже старое - oldDiveceID
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
} // конец функции checkCountOfMyID_inFirebase
}
```

ps/
усилить уникальность deviceID можно добавив + UUID.randomUUID().toString()

```
curentDeviceID = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID) + UUID.randomUUID().toString();     // текущий deviceID + randomNumber
```

Comment: Не пишите вопросы в поле для ответов.